# Can't set my fab icon to bottom right of my page

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I'm having trouble inserting the fab icon on the bottom right of my app even I set the anchor to `bottom|right` can you guys please help me doing this because the fab icon appears on the top left portion of the app.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.kun.carkila.OwnerTabs">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/plus"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/container"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_directions_car_white_48dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/container"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#990000"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:background="#990000">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I believe your parent `ViewGroup` has to be a `CoordinatorLayout` in order to anchor `Views` to one another.

Comment: @Emmanuel - yes, the next parent to that linearLayout is the Coordinator Layout.

Comment: @Emmanuel - updated the code sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This  should work! use

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_alignParent="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_directions_car_white_48dp"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />
```

woah where's ur relative layout gone which was parent of this floating button?

Answer (score 2):

First, to use the anchor attribute you should have CoordinatorLayout as parent view.
Second, your Floating button view is in AppBarLayout, which will always be at top of screen.

Take the floating button out of AppBarLayout and useCoordinatorLayout as parent view.

Comment: But when its on the coordinator layout (which is the next parent to the linear layout. The fab icon is not clickable.